# Emacs bookmark like jump to a possibly open file without changing cursor position

Tags: emacs

Is there an existing option to jump to a file(if file is already open, jump to existing buffer) *without changing the previous cursor position in the opened file* and ignoring the location recorded in the bookmark?

This is useful for quickly changing buffers with keyboard shortcuts like Alt-1, S-1 to load/save some numeric bookmarks.

Comment: Never mind, found out that bookmark-location and find-file can together implement this. 

(defun bookmark-jump-no-loc-change (bk)
      "Like bookmark-jump but preserves caret"   
      (find-file (bookmark-location bk)))

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer. Or else consider deleting the question, if you think it and the answer won't help others. (I think it will help others.) Also, consider clarifying the question: without changing the point from what? I *think* you want to open the file targeted by a bookmark, but you don't want point to move to the position recorded by the bookmark.

Comment: Just changed the terminology in the question. Point was what emacs used in docs, but cursor is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which was actually really simple. The bookmark-location function gives the file of a bookmark. Find-file opens a buffer/file with working cursor. So, one can define a function like

(defun bookmark-jump-preserve-working-cursor (bk)
 "Like bookmark-jump but preserves caret"
 (find-file (bookmark-location bk)))

Then, one can add keybindings like Alt-1, S-1 to load/save a position to numeric bookmarks.